# WPF DataGrid RowHeaderStyle

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have created a dataGrid and it is necessary to have the selectionUint set to:

```
 SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
```

So to select an entire row, I am using the RowHeader.
The default height that I have is small so the header Re-size separator is always getting in the way from being able to select a full row. is there a way to turn re-size off within a RowHeader?

```
            <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value=" "/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: You don't want to use `DataGridColumn.CanUserResize`?

Comment: does "CanUserResizeRows=False" not do what you need?

Comment: That is exactly what I need, shame on me for not finding that in the documentation.
Thank you